# The yarn logs command looks at a wrong directory, how can I fix this?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a hadoop cluster, on which there are two data nodes and one name node. In addition, I have a worker node from which I run hadoop commands and which points to the hadoop data nodes for execution.

When I run an application, it runs and stores the application log in `/app-logs/hdfs/logs`. The hadoop nodes that run the application are installed with version 3.1.1.3.

When I then try to run `yarn logs -applicationId application_1613400075634_0173` on the worker node, the yarn command does not return a value, and instead prints these lines:

```
    File /app-logs/hdfs/logs-tfile/application_1613400075634_0173 does not exist.
    File /app-logs/hdfs/bucket-logs-tfile/0173/application_1613400075634_0173 does not exist.


    Can not find any log file matching the pattern: [ALL] for the application: application_1613400075634_0173
    Can not find the logs for the application: application_1613400075634_0173 with the appOwner: hdfs
```

The worker node is installed with hadoop binaries version 3.3.

What do I need to change in the configuration in order for the yarn command to look at `/app-logs/hdfs/logs` instead of `/app-logs/hdfs/logs-tfile` or `bucket-logs-tfile`? The file `/app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_1613400075634_0173` does exist, but yarn looks at different directories.

Running the yarn command on the hadoop nodes themselves does work. It's only on the worker node that it doesn't.